# how can I run the apple Storekit in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, simulator, storekit

Normally, this can't be done.  I have written a class which wraps around the usual Storekit functionality and will allow an app to behave (while running on the simulator) as if the Storekit transaction had succeeded.

I have written a blog post about the design decisions behind the code, which can be read here and includes a download link:
   http://code-evolution.blogspot.com/2010/05/evolved-code-example-1-simplestore-for.html

Or you can just grab the sample project from this location:
  simplestoreevolved.googlecode.com/files/SimpleStoreEvolved.zip

Enjoy

T.

Comment: I have no idea why no one has upvoted this. I guess not that many people are using in app purchases.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Joseph, but I'm not that concerned about it.  if people need it, their search should lead them here  :)

Comment: but the [docs][1] say that IAP can be fully tested in the sim, except for hosted content..



  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW3

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a parallel solution, developed in the same timeframe:

https://github.com/millenomi/simstorekit